# Change Number Format for Range

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub FormatThreeDecimals()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastCell

Set ws = Worksheets("Summary")
lastCell = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Select
Set rng = [B4:LastCell]

Range("rng").NumberFormat = "0.000"

End Sub
```

I want define the range B4:lastCell with the variable rng, then apply "0.000" Number Format to it.  I am having issues setting the range properly.

Edit: I receive Run-time error '424': Oject required when my code hits the line Set rng = [B4:LastCell].

Comment: `Range(rng)`  not `"rng"` since it's your variable

Comment: I have switched that part, thank you.  I still have issue with the piece where I set rng = [B4:LastCell], I think this is incorrect method or syntax.

Comment: Using `[]` implies evaluation.  You would need to write `Range("B4:B" & cells(4,2).end(xldown).row)` or somethign similar

Comment: So this method truncates the numbers, how would I adapt this to round to 2 decimals?

Comment: I added ActiveWorkbook.PrecisionAsDisplayed = True and now the stored values are matching the displayed values, but I question whether this rounded or just truncated it a step further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim lastCell As Range
Set ws = Worksheets("Summary")
Set lastCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
Set rng = ws.Range("b4", lastCell)
rng.NumberFormat = "0.000"
```